# How to COUNT GROUP BY using JPARepository JPASpecificationExecutor with CustomSpecification

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have jpa repository as :

```
public interface MyRepository extends JPARepository<MyObject>, JPASpecificationExecutor<MyObject>{
}
```

And customSpecification

```
CustomComplexSpecification implements Specification<MyObject>{
... complex logic for object depending on input 
}
```

Normally I am fetching the records like this

```
myRepository.findAll(new CustomComplexSpecification(..input fields);
```

Now I want to get the counts with group by clause

```
    SELECT field1, field2, field3, count(*) from MYTABLE
 where (criteria from complex specification) group by field1, field2, field3;
```

How to do this GROUP BY and COUNT with jpaRepository and CustomSpecification as above

Note: I could do complete count like this

```
myRepository.count(new CustomComplexSpecification(..input fields);
```

Help me get count with group by and fields. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA supports rewrite query sql, like:

```
public interface ResumeDao extends JpaRepository<Resume, Long>, 
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<Resume> {

  @Query("from Resume where id = ?1")
  public List<Resume> findByJpql(Long id);

  @Query(value = "select * from tb_resume where id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
  public Resume findBySql(Long id);
}
```

So you can try to rewrite a SQL and the corresponding method ?

Comment: Thanks for your response, But my where clause is complex and depends on various parameters (present/not present) and dynamic inputs ~ thats why using CustomComplexSpecification